# Are there any MVC sample applications with BDD specs to use as a reference?

Tags: unit-testing, bdd

I'm learning BDD: how to write effective tests, what to test, and what to leave. I am also struggling with the exact definition of "Behavior" in BDD.

Are there any MVC sample applications with BDD specs to use as a reference?

Answer (score 1):

[CodeCampServer](http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/) uses BDD style "tests" with NBehave. For example, here is one of their [controller test classes](http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4755c1386bff#src/UnitTests/UI/Controllers/AdminControllerTester.cs).

Answer (score 1):

[Steve Sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/) writes [a lengthy blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/03/behavior-driven-development-bdd-with-specflow-and-aspnet-mvc/) on BDD with SpecFlow on an example ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 1):

BDD usually refers specifically to the "Given, When, Then" grammar. This is the style that SpecFlow, NBehave, and, basically, any framework supporting the [Gherkin language](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin), provide. And that is,

```
Given the system is in some state.
When I perform some action.
Then the system does x -or- is in some new state.
```

Tools like MSpec provide what's been called "context specification" grammar. And that looks like

```
(Establish your initial state... not technically a part of the grammar)
When I perform some action
It (the system) should do x -or- be in some state
```

This naming/grammar argument has been made before by big names like Scott Bellware on the [Herding Code podcast](http://herdingcode.com/?p=176) and [various articles](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0805061&page=1).